# How to validate input in a field on webpage without reloading the webpage?

Tags: html, jquery, django, ajax

(I am a beginner in django and html)
How can I weed out spam entries in a particular field while taking input from a user?
Also, how to show a message to the user that the entered value is not accepted because it's a spam, without reloading the webpage.

[image: Field]

For eg., in the field shown in image, if the user enters a number or something like test123 or something else that's not a proper name, my webpage should show a message to the user without loading the webpage that the entered value is not valid. I am also okay with putting a button that says validate to validate this name field value. How can I achieve this using Django+html+jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use the pattern attribute:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-zÀ-ž][A-zÀ-ž\s]+">
```

The browser will automatically check when you submit the form.

`A-z` stands for: latin characters.

`À-ž` stands for diacritics.

`\s` stands for space.

Note that the above patters requires the name to start with a letter and have at least 2 characters to be valid.

In Django you can define your form field like so:

```
full_name = forms.CharField(label='Full name', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"pattern":"[A-zÀ-ž][A-zÀ-ž\s]+"}))
```

Comment: awesome, thanks, let me try this

Comment: I am defining this field in my models.py that get used in the forms.py like so:
name = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Port Name',blank=True,null=True)

Is there a way to add patterns to the models like you mentioned for forms?

Comment: You need to override the clean_name method in your form definition and do the validation there. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Comment: thanks, if I use this method in my form definition, how can I make use of this method on the webpage without submitting/reloading? Is there a way to call this method in the html?

Comment: No, that's server-side. For client-side use the pattern above, or other methods involving javascript.

Comment: thanks, the pattern worked for me. I didn't realize that it validates the field as early as on clicking submit so that works for me since it doesn't reload the page at all. Is there a way to skip specific bad words such as "test" or "test123" using regex or some other way?

Comment: Technically yes, but it get really really complicated, really fast so you're better off doing that validation in code.